# Underwater Distance Sensing

Tags: sensor, robotics, distance, underwater

I'm looking to measure distances from a submersed robotics project in the range of 1 to 20 feet (around there at least).  However, the only options I seem to come across are rather heavy sonar modules that cost hundreds of dollars.  Are there lighter, cheaper alternatives?  I don't need great resolution or accuracy, just a decent measurement.  Perhaps it's possible to waterproof a normal distance sensor (IR or ultrasonic)?

I intend to interface the sensor with a microcontroller so it would be nice to have something that outputs 0-5 V, but that's not a requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: IR probably will not work very well, water absorbs red light. Ultrasonic sounds good, but i have no idea how well it works underwater.

Comment: I have a feeling you should be able to waterproof piezo elements rather easily for underwater operation, both as a speaker and a mic. I have never tried through, so don't hook up anything expensive to it if you do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultrasound would be your best shot. A quick search on the web tells me that unless you want do do a significant amount of work yourself it's not going to be cheap. Transducers from [Senix](http://www.robotshop.com/world/senix-tspc-30s1-waterproof-ultrasonic-sensor-1.html) cost about $500, but if you can get a hold of a waterproof ultrasound sensor for parking aid systems and is able to build the tx-amplifier, the transmit/receive switch, and do the signal processing in a uC you should be done for a lot less than that.

Answer (score 2):

Fish-finders like [this Garmin unit](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?pID=85268&ra=true) are quite inexpensive at about $100. Buy one of those and use the transducer. You might even be able to buy the transducer quite cheaply as a spare.

Comment: ...but understand that the transducer will output data which can be turned into something you'd see on a fish finder LCD. It will not be trivial to parse!

Comment: The transducer simply emits a pulse and receives the echo. The processing is done by the main unit.

Comment: Precisely!  But the signal processing required to transform that echo into "the nearest solid object is x feet away" is going to be very difficult.

Comment: It just involves measuring the time for the reflected pulse to arrive back at the transducer.